# Difference between !typeof str == "string" and typeof str != "string"

Tags: javascript, coercion

I was  writing a simple if condition that checks the type of the input. I used `!typeof str == "string"`
it did not work, so i used `typeof str != "string"`  instead of it. it worked. this is the function:

```
function reverseStr(str) {
  if (typeof str != "string" || !str) {
      return "Please enter a valid str";
  }

  var oldList = str.split("");
  var newList = [];
  for (let i = oldList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      newList.push(oldList[i]);
  }
return newList.join("");
```

}

so what is the difference between them?

Comment: `!typeof str` is likely to be the value `false` ... think of it as `(!typeof str) == "string"` ... and !truthyvalue === false

Comment: `!(typeof str == "string")` this will work same as `typeof str != "string"`

Comment: @HassanImam - yes, but the question was ... oh, never mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to operator precedence (`!` has a greater precedence that `==`), `!typeof str == "string"` is equivalent to `(!typeof str) == "string"`, which means `the boolean value opposite to the type of str is equal to "string"` and will always be false since `!typeof str` returns `false`, and `false != "string"`.

`typeof str != "string"` works because it means `the type of str is not equal to "string"`.